# Pruning Blockstore has been running for days

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, block, synchronization, pruning

After activating the core (Testnet - Pruned) with the command `bitcoin-qt`  i received the following error:
`Corrupt Block Database`
I restarted the synchronization always using the Pruned mode.
The core has been in the "Pruning Blockstore" state for days.
Below is the debug.log:

```
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Config file: /root/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using at most 125 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using 0 threads for script verification
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z scheduler thread start
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Config options rpcuser and rpcpassword will soon be deprecated. Locally-run instances may remove rpcuser to use cookie-based auth, or may be replaced with rpcauth. Please see share/rpcauth for rpcauth auth generation.
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using wallet directory /root/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z init message: Verifica portafoglio/i...
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z Using wallet /root/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets
2020-05-25T06:58:54Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/root/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/database ErrorFile=/root/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/db.log
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z init message: Caricamento bloccati...
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z Cache configuration:
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z * Using 2.0 MiB for block index database
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z * Using 8.0 MiB for chain state database
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z * Using 440.0 MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1 MiB of unused mempool space)
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z init message: Caricamento dell'indice dei blocchi...
2020-05-25T06:58:55Z Opening LevelDB in /root/.bitcoin/testnet3/blocks/index
2020-05-25T06:59:11Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2020-05-25T06:59:11Z Using obfuscation key for /root/.bitcoin/testnet3/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2020-05-25T06:59:43Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file = 3
2020-05-25T06:59:43Z LoadBlockIndexDB: last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=3020, size=100801650, heights=203040...206095, time=2014-03-05...2014-03-21)
2020-05-25T06:59:43Z Checking all blk files are present...
2020-05-25T06:59:44Z LoadBlockIndexDB(): Block files have previously been pruned
2020-05-25T06:59:44Z Opening LevelDB in /root/.bitcoin/testnet3/chainstate
2020-05-25T06:59:44Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2020-05-25T06:59:44Z Using obfuscation key for /root/.bitcoin/testnet3/chainstate: fff82f9bc3f0e479
2020-05-25T06:59:44Z init message: Verifica blocchi...
2020-05-25T06:59:46Z  block index           51276ms
2020-05-25T06:59:46Z init message: Caricamento portafoglio...
2020-05-25T06:59:46Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/root/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/database ErrorFile=/root/.bitcoin/testnet3/wallets/db.log
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z [default wallet] Wallet File Version = 169900
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z [default wallet] Keys: 2018 plaintext, 0 encrypted, 2018 w/ metadata, 2018 total. Unknown wallet records: 0
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z [default wallet] Wallet completed loading in             315ms
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z [default wallet] setKeyPool.size() = 2000
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z [default wallet] mapWallet.size() = 11
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z [default wallet] mapAddressBook.size() = 17
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z Unsetting NODE_NETWORK on prune mode
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z init message: Pruning del blockstore...
2020-05-25T06:59:47Z Imported mempool transactions from disk: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 expired, 0 already there
2020-05-25T07:31:14Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 1890 seconds ago)
2020-05-25T07:41:44Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 2520 seconds ago)
2020-05-25T07:52:14Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 3150 seconds ago)
2020-05-25T08:02:44Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 3780 seconds ago)
2020-05-25T08:13:14Z Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 4410 seconds ago)
```

> What happened?
>
> How can it be solved?

Comment: [This is a better place to write bug reports.](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues)

Comment: What is your bitcoin.conf? and inside log, I don't see the actual block height, can you add these details?